# Notify if data has been sent

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm just new in codeigniter with ajax approach. Well, I have a form wherein the user needs to fill up all the fields because it's required. I've done the error messages if the field is empty. I'm getting a response through JSON from the controller, if data is valid or not. Now my problem is how can I appear the notification if the data has been sent to the database? Sending data is working, btw.

**Form**

```
<form action="<?=base_url();?>execute/insert" id="formAddContent" autocomplete="off" class="nobottommargin" method="POST">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
             <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">Title <small>*</small></label>
                  <input type="text" name="content_title" id="content_title" class="sm-form-control">
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Type <small>*</small></label>
                   <select name="content_type" id="content_type" class="sm-form-control">
                       <option value="">Type</option>
                       <option value="try">Try</option>
                   </select>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-12">
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="">Description <small>*</small></label>
                 <textarea class="required sm-form-control" id="content_body" name="content_body" rows="6" cols="30" required></textarea>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 margintop-sm">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="data-content--submit">Submit</button>
         </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function validate($name, $label, $check) {
    return $this->form_validation->set_rules($name, $label, $check);
}

public function insert() {
    $data = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

    $name        = array('content_title','content_type','content_body');
    $label       = array('Title', 'Type', 'Content');
    $verify      = 'trim|required';
    $this->validate($name[0], $label[0], $verify);
    $this->validate($name[1], $label[1], $verify);
    $this->validate($name[2], $label[2], $verify);
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">', '</p>');

    if($this->form_validation->run()) {
         $data['success'] = true;
    } else {
         foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $data['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
         }
    }
    echo json_encode($data);

    $data = array (
        $name[0] => $this->pass($name[0]),
        $name[1] => $this->pass($name[1]),
        $name[2] => $this->pass($name[2])
    );

    $result = $this->model->CreateContent($data);

    if($result) {
        redirect('master/content','refresh');
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public function CreateContent($data) {
    $check = $this->db->select('content_title')->from('tblposts')->where(array('content_title' => $data['content_title']))->get();
    if($check->num_rows() > 0) {
        $this->notify([true,'#336699','#fff', 'Title already exists.']);
        return $check;
    } else {
        $result = $this->db->insert('tblposts', $data);
        $this->notify([true,'#336699','#fff', 'New content has been added.']);
        return $result;
    }
}

public function notify($data) {
    echo json_encode(['success'=>$data[0],'bgcolor'=>$data[1],'color'=>$data[2],'message'=>$data[3]]);
}
```

**jQuery-AJAX**

```
$('#formAddContent').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
        content_title: $('#content_title').val(),
        content_type: $('#content_type').val(), 
        content_body: $('#content_body').val()
    };

    var url = $(this).attr('action');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', url: url, data: data, cache: false, dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data) {
            if(data.success == true) {
                successful(data.success,data.bgcolor,data.color,data.message);
            } else {
                $.each(data.messages, function(key,value) {
                    var element = $('#' + key);
                    element.closest('div.form-group')
                    .removeClass('has-error')
                    .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success')
                    .find('.text-danger').remove();
                    element.after(value);
                });
            }
        }
    });
});

//Custom method if the request was success. 
function successful(data,bgcolor,color,message) {
    data == true ? notify(bgcolor,color,message) : notify(bgcolor,color,message);
}

//Amaran Notification
function notify(bgcolor,color,message) {
    $.amaran({
        'theme'     : 'colorful', 'content'   : {bgcolor: bgcolor,color: color,message: message},
        'position'  : 'top right', 'outEffect' : 'slideBottom'
    });
}
```

**JSON return array**

```
{"success":true,"messages":[]}{"success":true,"bgcolor":"#336699","color":"#fff","message":"New content has been added."}
```

Comment: How do you want to get your notification?

Comment: If data has been sent then it will notify.

Comment: I mean to ask that if you want it by email ?

Comment: Yeah sure. You can email me @johnwujeck1234@gmail.com

Comment: No no. I mean to say that you want the notification by email bro!

Comment: Lol sorry. No... I'm using amaran notification.

Comment: You can try to add the notification code as <?php echo '<script>...your script...</script>';?> like this in the notify function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off remove this section:

```
if($result) {
        redirect('master/content','refresh');
    }
```

this will **not** redirect anything but the ajax request (not page submitting the request) which is 99% of the time not the desired behavior and it will prevent the success json array from getting rendered meaning you should be getting console errors. If you need to redirect do so via js in your success function. If you are confused about this note that js is client-side and php is server-side.

Once removing this (the rest of your code seems fine) the page should render a success message however it won't redirect. If you chose to add a js redirect function after `successful(data.success,data.bgcolor,data.color,data.message);` you probably would never see the message. In such a case when redirection is 100% desired you should add a flash message in your controller code, and redirect in js instead of using `successful()`. Then if you next page is configured to see the flash message it will show up there.

UPDATE:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
    $data['success'] = true;
} else {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $data['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
    }
    // this should be here!
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit; // otherwise create content will trigger even on failed fv!
}

$data = array(
    $name[0] => $this->pass($name[0]),
    $name[1] => $this->pass($name[1]),
    $name[2] => $this->pass($name[2])
);
```

Comment: I removed this line but it doesn't work. No notification appear.

    if($result) {
        redirect('master/content','refresh');
    }

Comment: First check for console errors then add a console.log(data); in the first like of the success fuction. Report back please.

Comment: Like this one? success:function(data) { console.log(data); if(data.success) {sucessul(); } else { } }

Comment: Yes then you can see in the console the array that is being returned from the response

Comment: No array return in the console. What should I do?

Comment: Well that means the success function isn't being reached.... Do you see any errors in the console? Can you verify the function is being reached?

Comment: I haven't seen any errors in the console so far. I think yes.

Comment: Well add an alert or something at the top of the function to make sure. Then enable error reporting in ci if you haven't already and check what response you are getting in the network pane under the reponsnse for the page request.

Comment: I added an alert at the top of $.ajax({}); it works, but if I add an alert inside the success function the alert doesn't work.

Comment: find what you are getting back from the server: https://imgur.com/a/DTT276h (example)

Comment: Here is the response from network pane.{"success":true,"messages":[]}{"success":true,"bgcolor":"#336699","color":"#fff","message":"New content has been added."}

Comment: if that is the case I'm stumped as to why `success:function(data) { console.log(data);` isn't giving you the same in the console or at the very least an error saying your json format is wrong (if it were)

Comment: you **would** get an error. i don't know why you aren't - never seen this before

Comment: Oh wait think i found something (still not sure why you arent getting an error). but check the updated code

Comment: If i were you, to make everything more dry. Just return true/false in the model function (as it isn't supposed to handle output by design) and move the notifications all into the controller and use one function to generate the json_encodes via a helper or something. i have a class i made and use: https://pastebin.com/JLYFQq1A and although the syntax is a bit different it works like `$this->response->success()->add(array('bg_color'=>'#fff'))->json();` or for form validation errors `$this->response->form_errors()->json()` the syntax is just a bit different than what you are using

Comment: Should I copy all the codes in the link that you provided?

Comment: It's only a helper type model. Use it if you want.

Comment: Is it possible to reload the page after notification appeared? If yes, how?

Comment: I have no familiarity with the notification plug-in you are using but if you could bind an event to the on close event when the notification self dismisses or to the close event when the user clicks the x (if it has it) then you can redirect. Generally you wouldn't even use Ajax for any of this as if you want to go to a different page after post then you should just do that regularly and compeletely exclude Ajax and handle the messages with session based flash messages